# Do mirror neurons fire during visualization?

Tags: visualization, mirror-neurons

It is known that mirror neurons fire when watching another person performing the same activity. But do they also fire when visualizing oneself performing an activity (visualizing performing the activity in the first person in particular)?
And if they do, what are the implications for learning an activity or visualizing goals?